# Callout to web service doesn't work depending the profile I'm using

Tags: soap-api, custom-button, permissions, profile, callout

I have a customized button that once you click it, a new window it's open displaying some data from an external app, getting the data through a SOAP web service.

If I'm logged as System Administrator it works fine.
[image]

But if I'm logged as any other user profile it doesn't work. At first, it complained about permissions, so I gave other profiles the permissions needed for the VFPage involved, Apex Classes involved and Objects involved.

Now, it doesn't complain about permissions. After click the button, the expected window opens fine, but, it doesn't display the data.
[image]

¿Any idea what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I've followed the given tips, and using the Debug Log for two different profiles, the result is exactly the same:
[image]

As you can see, the same result is returned from the web service callout.

Comment: Try capturing the debug log of the user in question. Look for CALLOUT_REQUEST log messages that occur for the SOAP request. If they aren't appearing something else is preventing the call from occurring.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm trying with the Developer Console, but I have a problem. I'm using System.runAs(u) in order to capture the debug log for different users, but I have the exception: "System.runAs can only be used within a test method". So, I include it in a test method and now the exception is that in a test method: "Methods defined as TestMethod don't allow calls to a web service; the test will be ignored".  Which are my options??!!!

Comment: You don't need to use `System.runAs(u)` to capture a log for another user. Either use Setup > Monitoring > Debug Log and select the user or select show logs  for all users in the developer console.

Comment: @DanielBallinger question updated by following your tip. Debug Log for both users is exactly the same...

Comment: From the logs it would appear the web service callout is functioning as expected for both users regardless of the profile. You might need to following the logging further to see why the Visualforce page isn't rendering as expected for one users profile.

Comment: How does the data get from the web service response onto the Visualforce page? Based on the logging the problem appears to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the class(es) for all required profiles?   It's one thing to enable the page, but you'll also have to enable the supporting code.

Comment: Yes, I've enabled all the Apex Classes involved in process. Basicly, the controller for the VFPage, and the classes that make the callout to the SOAP web service.

Comment: Sorry, looks like my edit didn't take!   did you log in as one of the users and confirm they are able to access the data?  From your description, it sounds like the code fires and runs without error, but there may legitimately be no results for the users.   As an Admin, you have the permission SeeAllData=TRUE, so this may be why you are able to return data when testing

Comment: Updated question, you can see I've confirmed with two differents profiles and only Admin is working.

Comment: Have yo gone to Setup> Debug Logs> and enabled Debug logs for your user?   In your class which is runnin the query, make sure you put somthing like system.debug('my result set size' + myList.size()); to verify you actually have results.  From here, you can then loging as the user, attempt to access the page, logout and then view the logs. I suspect since you have no errors, then something else is amiss, likely with the query.   Lastly, are you checking to see the response from the webservice callout?

Comment: Question updated. Debug Log for both users is exactly the same...